# Puedo usar getElementsByClassName con un operador negativo?

Tags: javascript

Tengo una gran lista de elementos con la clase `rdrDays`, y algunos de ellos tienen otra clase llamada `disabled`.

Yo quiero aplicar un `eventListener` a los elementos que tienen la clase `rdrDays` pero NO tienen la clase `disabled`

Algo como

```
document.getElemenstByClassName("rdrDays&(:not)disabled");
```

Es posible filtrar estos elementos con la funcion `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: Intenta con `document.querySelectorAll(".rdrDays:not(.disabled)")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay múltiples caminos, pero te recomiendo dos.
El primero tendrás mas control teniendo una lista con los elementos específicos que necesitas.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("rdrDays");
var filteredElements = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  if (!elements[i].classList.contains("disabled")) {
    filteredElements.push(elements[i]);
  }
}
```

Por otro lado, podrías utilizar querySelectorAll

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".rdrDays:not(.disabled)");
```

Te sugereriría revisar el siguiente enlace
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574692/javascript-and-queryselector

Y si tienes dudas revisar directamente esta documentación

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Answer (score 1):

No, no puede usar el `getElementsByClassName` con un operador de negación (por ejemplo, `:not`) para seleccionar elementos que no tienen una clase específica. Puede lograr un resultado similar utilizando el `:not(.classname)` con un selector de CSS que excluye la clase, como `:not(.classname)`.

Por ejemplo:

```
document.querySelectorAll(':not(.classname)');
```

Esto seleccionaría todos los elementos que no tienen la clase "nombre de clase".